# Download CSV from url in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I have a URL that I want to regularly download from. It can only be accessed from a logged in account which requires javascript support to do so, and so I'm forced to use Selenium with PhantomJS, trust me. Otherwise, I would just use urllib for this, but it gives me a sign in error.

It's a CSV file, with a maximum of 1000 rows, and about 6 columns.

I want to eventually get this CSV into a list. Does anyone know how to download a CSV with Selenium Webdriver?

Thanks so much.

Edit: I'm just looking to download a CSV from a URL in Selenium. Nothing else.

Comment: Can you provide the URL, and some dummy username+password, and then tell where the download button/link is located?

Comment: BTW, downloading the CSV is pretty easy with Selenium. The main problem is how to handle the 'Save As' popup that the browser usually generates.

Comment: The platform I'm using has nothing to do with the question. I just need a generic way to download a CSV from a URL in Selenium. Yes, after opening the URL, a Save As dialog appears. If you want a URL to test on, here's one: http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv

Comment: Not a duplicate, that one is in Java, and can't really understand it.

Comment: @rvraghav93 The accepted answer for that post doesn't really answer the question and the linked blog post isn't very helpful either.

Comment: What is the problem with `webdriver.get(url)`? The "Save As" dialogue popup, or some other issue?

Comment: @cpburnz ya thats true ... sorry for the mistake ... that code doesnt work either !

Comment: Is it possible to get the session id and cookies and the pass it to urllib / requests for downloading the file?
for instance `browser.session_id` and `browser.get_cookies()` yield the session id and cookies... these can be passed to requests. Is is possible to do it that way ?

Comment: That sounds like it may work. I know nothing about cookies. Does anyone else know?

Comment: I would like to get help with this as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its actually pretty simple. Using another answer I gave in stack over flow

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21871600/2423379

**EDIT: Running Firefox in Headless mode**

Requirements:

- `sudo apt-get install xvfb` (or equivalent command in ur distro)
- `pip install --user xvfbwrapper`

And code part

```
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb

vdisplay = Xvfb()
vdisplay.start()

# launch stuff inside virtual display here

vdisplay.stop()
```

Ref: [Firefox-selenium in headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300672/2423379)

Comment: Thanks, however I'm using PhantomJS instead of Firefox, as I need it to be headerless.

Comment: I had a similar requirement. However I was not able to do the csv download with PhantomJS. But the bright side is that you can use Firefox is headless mode..that's what I am doing right now..I have updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

How about `page_source` attribute?

```
browser.get("http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv")
csv_file = browser.page_source
print(csv_file)
```

Try this, my friend. I use Selenium + Python + HTMLUnit, working like a breeze.

Hope it works for your PhantomJS